# Getting field value by request.auth.token.name

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

does anybody have solution for this?

```
allow create, delete, update: if request.resource.data["request.auth.token.name"] == request.auth.uid;
```

Im getting error:

> Property request.auth.token.name is undefined on object.

Im trying to get field value which has name of user's name and contains user uid:

```
usersUsername: userUid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes.  Quotes always mean the literal text inside it and not the value of some variable or expression. If you want some expression value, just put that directly in the square brackets to look up its value in the object.

```
allow create, delete, update: if request.resource.data[request.auth.token.name] == request.auth.uid;
```